# how to correctly configure Httpd basic auth for pass through proxy

Tags: configuration, httpd, http-basic-authentication, jira, confluence

I have been asked to set up an basic auth prompt in front of our Jira server.
I am using a proxypassthrough on httpd to allow access to jira in the first place.

When ever I try to connect I am prompted and upon completing login , I am sent to the proper page but it's all white with no code return. Logs show that I am returning a 401 each time though.

Here is my ssl.conf

```
ServerName jira.mydomain.com


ProxyPreserveHost On
# setup the proxy
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /  http://jira.mydomain.com:6666/
ProxyPassReverse /  http://jira.mydomain.com:6666/

 <Location />
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Too Many Secrets"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.foopasswdfile
    Require valid-user
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Httpd access logs show:

```
GET /login.action?os_destination=%2Findex.action&permissionViolation=true HTTP/1.1" 401 381 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.91 Safari/537.36
```

I'm not sure if you need anymore information, please let me know and I will provide this.

Any ideas as to what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Well, after a few searches , I ran into something that had this added to this and it worked.

Added this to my httpd conf.

```
RequestHeader unset Authorization
```

my over all configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>


    ServerName dev.mydomain.com
    RequestHeader unset Authorization


    ProxyPreserveHost On
    # setup the proxy

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Required"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.magicalpasswdfile
    Require valid-user
</Proxy>


    ProxyPass /  http://dev.mydomain.com:8091/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://dev.mydomain.com:8091/

#... SSL STUFF

</VirtualHost>
```